# http delete:"Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target."

Tags: json, angular, angular-http

I am trying to use `http delete` in Angular 2 but I always get `Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.` typescript error. Here is the code:

```
let headers= new Headers();
                   headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');   

                   let options= new RequestOptions({headers:headers});
                   this.http.delete('http://sample.com/XXX/api.php/cart?filter=cart.customer_id,eq,21&transform=1',options,headers)
                   .subscribe((ok)=>{
                     console.log("Successfully Deleted." +ok)
                   }, (err) => {
                     this.showPopup("Oops!", "Something went wrong on deletion." +err);
                   });
```

I do not understand why is there error. Hope you guys can help me. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Headers is a property on options, which is the second parameter. There is no need to add headers as well.

```
     this.http.delete('http://sample.com/XXX/api.php/cart?filter=cart.customer_id,eq,21&transform=1',options)
               .subscribe( ...);
```

Comment: thnak you for the response sir. It worked for me. But still I cannot delete anything.

Comment: What response do you get back?

Comment: Here is the response sir:  Successfully Deleted.Response with status: 200 OK for URL: http://sample.com/XXX/api.php/cart?filter=cart.customer_id,eq,21&transform=1